# Wordpress: Remove site info in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, footer

I've a little problem. I'm developing a website with wordpress and the theme "barletta". This theme adds a text into the footer that I want to remove. Normally I do this by editing the footer.php but with this theme it's different. I have to change the functions.php cause there's this code snipet:

```
function barletta_footer_credits() {
?>
<div class="site-info">
<?php if (get_theme_mod('barletta_footer_text') == '') { ?>
&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?><?php esc_html_e('. All rights reserved.', 'barletta'); ?>
<?php } else { echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'barletta_footer_text', 'barletta' ) ); } ?>
</div><!-- .site-info -->

<?php
$nofollow="";
if (!is_home()) { $nofollow="rel=\"nofollow\""; }
printf( esc_html__( 'Theme by %1$s Powered by %2$s', 'barletta' ) , '<a href="http://moozthemes.com/" target="_blank" '.$nofollow.'>MOOZ Themes</a>', '<a href="http://wordpress.org/" target="_blank">WordPress</a>');
} 
add_action( 'barletta_footer', 'barletta_footer_credits' );
```

I'm not good in PHP so here my question: how do I have to edit this code that the site-info-div will be still displayed but not the printed text (powered by...)?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last if check:

```
function barletta_footer_credits() {
?>
    <div class="site-info">
        <?php if (get_theme_mod('barletta_footer_text') == '') { ?>
            &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?><?php esc_html_e('. All rights reserved.', 'barletta'); ?>
        <?php } else { echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'barletta_footer_text', 'barletta' ) ); } ?>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
<?php
}
add_action( 'barletta_footer', 'barletta_footer_credits' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code from

```
function barletta_footer_credits() {
?>
<div class="site-info">
<?php if (get_theme_mod('barletta_footer_text') == '') { ?>
&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?><?php esc_html_e('. All rights reserved.', 'barletta'); ?>
<?php } else { echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'barletta_footer_text', 'barletta' ) ); } ?>
</div><!-- .site-info -->

<?php
$nofollow="";
if (!is_home()) { $nofollow="rel=\"nofollow\""; }
printf( esc_html__( 'Theme by %1$s Powered by %2$s', 'barletta' ) , '<a href="http://moozthemes.com/" target="_blank" '.$nofollow.'>MOOZ Themes</a>', '<a href="http://wordpress.org/" target="_blank">WordPress</a>');
} 
add_action( 'barletta_footer', 'barletta_footer_credits' );
```

With Following

```
function barletta_footer_credits() {
?>
<div class="site-info">
<?php if (get_theme_mod('barletta_footer_text') == '') { ?>
&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?><?php esc_html_e('. All rights reserved.', 'barletta'); ?>
<?php } else { echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'barletta_footer_text', 'barletta' ) ); } ?>
</div><!-- .site-info -->

} 
add_action( 'barletta_footer', 'barletta_footer_credits' );
```

That is just remove the whole block of

```
<?php
$nofollow="";
if (!is_home()) { $nofollow="rel=\"nofollow\""; }
printf( esc_html__( 'Theme by %1$s Powered by %2$s', 'barletta' ) , '<a href="http://moozthemes.com/" target="_blank" '.$nofollow.'>MOOZ Themes</a>', '<a href="http://wordpress.org/" target="_blank">WordPress</a>');
```